# Is booster dose needed for chinese vaccines

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

I can't seem to easily find such information and would greatly appreciate some help. Does anyone have information if booster (third) dose is required or recommended for Chinese Covid vaccine sinopharm? According to studies.

Comment: I don't know about studies, but they announced boosters https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202108/1232651.shtml

Comment: There is a study preprint [here](https://www.medrxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.07.23.21261026v1.full). Results are somewhat hard to parse, but the press has interpreted them as recommending a 3rd dose after 6 months.

Comment: I can't post comment, maybe someone can evaluate this: https://www.who.int/news/item/04-10-2021-interim-statement-on-booster-doses-for-covid-19-vaccination @Fizz what is your opinion on this?

Comment: @Fizz, the preprint is, as you note, a bit difficult to parse but the inference is that there is benefit to administering a boost at 6-8 months after completion of the original series, and that cellular immunity remains intact at that point, based on the fact that a neutralizing antibody response was elicited. A boost dose returned titers to levels consistent with completion of the original series, which was deemed adequate.